# How can I hide ImageView of specific item without knowing position?

Tags: android

What I want is when the item in listview not have image, the ImageView will be gone.Like this:

**Have image:**

[image]

**Not have image:**

[image]

Currently,I do this by add this code to getView method of adapter

```
if (mImageList.size() == 0) {
       mPostHolder.mChosenImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else if (mImageList.size() > 1) {

    for (int i = 0; i < mImageList.size(); i++) {
        mPostHolder.mChosenImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (((MemosModel) mMemoList.get(position)).getmMemoId() == (mImageList.get(i).getMemoId())) {
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImageList.get(i).getPath());
        mPostHolder.mChosenImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                        }
                    }
                }
```

But it is just make the ImageView of all Memos gone or visible,not specific ones like I want.

**Note:**

1 - I have a database with two table: "Memo" and "Image" and "Image" table
have 1 column "MemoId" which contain the id of Memo.

2 - ImageList is the array of Image objects which I get from "Image"
table.

3 - MemoList is the array of Memo objects which I get from "Memo".

**4 - I can't create image variable in Memo object,that's the request.**

I struggled with this problem for hours. Please help me to solve this!

**EDIT:** Add adapter

```
     @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {

         convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_timeline_post, parent, false);
         mPostHolder = new TimeLineHolder().new PostHolder();

          mPostHolder.mStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_status);
          mPostHolder.mChosenImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_posted);

          convertView.setTag(mPostHolder);
     } else {
            mPostHolder = (PostHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

    mPostHolder.mStatus.setText(((MemoObject) mMemoList.get(position)).getStatusText());

    if (mImageList.size() == 0) {
            mPostHolder.mChosenImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  } else if (mImageList.size() > 1) {

        for (int i = 0; i < mImageList.size(); i++) {
            if (( mMemoList.get(position)).getmMemoId() == (mImageList.get(i).getMemoId())) {
                mPostHolder.mChosenImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImageModelList.get(i).getPath());
                mPostHolder.mChosenImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);

        }
      }
   }
```

> The Image and Memo array is passed from my MainActivity.The array is get by just simple "Select * from..." query.

Comment: better you set a blank image or no image for your image view and setImageBitmap for those are present in your array list, this will help

Comment: But it will make a big blank between TextView and Button.

Comment: can you post your whole adapter class code ?

Comment: the adapter is very long, so I made it short, please take a look ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (mImageList.size() == 0) {
    mPostHolder.mPostedImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else if (mImageList.size() > 1) {

    for (int i = 0; i < mImageList.size(); i++) {
        if (((MemosModel) mMemoList.get(position)).getmMemoId() == (mImageList.get(i).getMemoId())) {
            if (mImageList.get(i).getPath().equals(null) || mImageList.get(i).getPath().equals("")) {
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImageList.get(i).getPath());
                mPostHolder.mChosenImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            } else {
                mPostHolder.mChosenImage.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
08-19 02:36:18.725: E/ID(13070): 929043207145744_951230201593711
08-19 02:36:18.729: E/PATH(13070): null
08-19 02:36:18.729: E/ID(13070): 929043207145744_951230201593711
08-19 02:36:18.737: E/PATH(13070): /mnt/sdcard/lifelog/929043207145744_951223071594424.png
08-19 02:36:18.737: E/ID(13070): 929043207145744_951223071594424
08-19 02:36:18.737: E/PATH(13070): /mnt/sdcard/lifelog/929043207145744_951223071594424.png
08-19 02:36:18.737: E/ID(13070): 929043207145744_951223071594424
```

Comment: I think we should setVisibility to GONE when getphath equals null, right? I editted it. Btw, I tried your method but it does not work. It's very weird,I make a logcat before the for loop and see that ImageList.size() have enough elements in database. Then I also make a logcat in the second if statement, but seem like it is never called.

Comment: Now,it's weirder. After I post this comment, it can be called @_@. But it become a mess,there are statuses with image,statuses without image,and statuses with blank image.

Comment: After I try to put logcat in the first if statement, I can see it the object in ImageList called double time.Maybe this is what cause problem, but I don't understand why it happen, please help me!

Comment: can you add mImageList.get(i).getPath().equals("null") with the if statement