# Why is this method called double time?

Tags: android

What I want is to hide the `ImageView` of specific item in the `ListView`, so I put this code to `getView` method of adapter:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mImageModelList.size(); i++) {
    if (((SNSPostModel) mComparableObjectList.get(position)).getAccountId().equals(mImageModelList.get(i).getSnsPostId())) {
        Log.e("PATH", mImageModelList.get(i).getPath());
        Log.e("ID", mImageModelList.get(i).getSnsPostId());
        if (mImageModelList.get(i).getPath().equals(null) || mImageModelList.get(i).getPath().equals("null")) {
                //Log.e("REMOVE", "REMOVE");
                //mPostHolder.mPostedImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
                mPostHolder.mPostedImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImageModelList.get(i).getPath());
                mPostHolder.mPostedImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is Logcat:

```
08-19 02:36:18.725: E/ID(13070): 929043207145744_951230201593711
08-19 02:36:18.729: E/PATH(13070): null
08-19 02:36:18.729: E/ID(13070): 929043207145744_951230201593711
08-19 02:36:18.737: E/PATH(13070): /mnt/sdcard/lifelog/929043207145744_951223071594424.png
08-19 02:36:18.737: E/ID(13070): 929043207145744_951223071594424
08-19 02:36:18.737: E/PATH(13070): /mnt/sdcard/lifelog/929043207145744_951223071594424.png
08-19 02:36:18.737: E/ID(13070): 929043207145744_951223071594424
```

As you can see, I don't understand why the object in `ImageModelList` is called double times. Please show me how to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, try to remove the for loop everything will be fine

Comment: Then change 'i' variables to 'position'

Comment: You should log `mComparableObjectList.get(position)).getAccountId()` before the loop, I think you have 2 duplicate id in your aray

Comment: @Sheychan The mImageModelList is not as same as mComparableObjectList.For more detail, please take a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068716/how-can-i-hide-imageview-of-specific-item-without-knowing-position/32068939#32068939

Answer (score 0):

the method `getView()` is not the place for what you want. This is the place where the `Adapter` take every position in the `ListView` and decide how to populate it and if he need to generate new `View` for this place.

Instead you can use `ListView.getChaildAt(int position) that bring you the View you want, or if you don't know the position you can use:

```
    YourCustomAdapter yourCustomAdapter = ((YourCustomAdapter)listView.getAdapter());
    for (int i = 0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++){
        View v = listView.getChildAt(i);
        //put your logic check here, use the yourCustomAdapter reference to read it data like mImageModelList. You need that all data will define as public 
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but I want to use ListView

Comment: it the same, jest replace it.

Comment: but where should I use it? in the getView method of Adapter or MainActivity or else? please explain to me more specific ;)

Comment: I edited my answer. If you want you could also hand to the Adapter your ListView in the constructor and use the for loop inside the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have to do in your getView method. 
You never run a for loop in getView().

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        mPostHolder= new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.snapshort_item_view, null);
        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        mPostHolder.mPostedImage= (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.snapshortImage);
        view.setTag(mPostHolder);
    } else {
        mPostHolder= (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
     // Here you need to check your condition for hiding the imageview or not. Replace "i" with "position" which is a parameter fot getView() method.
    if (mImageModelList.get(position).getPath().equals(null)
            || mImageModelList.get(position).getPath().equals("null")) {
        // Log.e("REMOVE", "REMOVE");
        // mPostHolder.mPostedImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        mPostHolder.mPostedImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImageModelList.get(i)
                .getPath());
        mPostHolder.mPostedImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    }

    return view;
}
```